# Class accepting data input by variable, function pointer or lambda

Tags: c++, template, lambda, c++20

## Background

I am writing a library that takes some data from the user and works with it. I was experimenting with ways to allow users to provide the data by the following methods:

- As a (global) variable (taken by a `const &`)
- As a function pointer
- As a lambda (taken by value)

I am aware that I can just wrap the variable or function in a lambda to achieve the same result, but I think I can learn something by doing it the "hard" way.

I am targeting C++20.

## Code

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>

template <class T, bool = std::is_invocable_v<T>>
struct GetDataType
{
    using type = typename std::invoke_result_t<T>;
};

template <class T>
struct GetDataType<T, false>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T, bool = std::is_invocable_v<T>>
struct GetSourceType
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
struct GetSourceType<T, false>
{
    using type = typename std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<T>>;
};

template <typename DataSource>
class DataGetter
{
public:
    using DataType = GetDataType<DataSource>::type;
    using DataSourceType = GetSourceType<DataSource>::type;

    DataGetter(const DataSource &f) : m_dataSource(f) {}

    [[nodiscard]] bool dataMatches(DataType refData) const
    {
        return refData == getData();
    }

private:
    DataSourceType m_dataSource;

    [[nodiscard]] DataType getData() const
    {
        if constexpr (std::invocable<DataSource>)
        {
            return std::invoke(m_dataSource);
        }
        else
        {
            return m_dataSource;
        }
    }
};

volatile uint32_t g_Data = 3;
uint32_t getData() { return g_Data + 1; }

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    DataGetter fromLocal(argc);
    DataGetter fromGlobal(g_Data);
    DataGetter fromLambda([&argc]()
                          { return argc + 1; });
    DataGetter fromFunctionPointer(&getData);

    assert(fromLocal.dataMatches(1));
    assert(fromGlobal.dataMatches(3));
    assert(fromLambda.dataMatches(2));
    assert(fromFunctionPointer.dataMatches(4));

    argc++;
    g_Data = g_Data + 1;

    assert(fromLocal.dataMatches(2));
    assert(fromGlobal.dataMatches(4));
    assert(fromLambda.dataMatches(3));
    assert(fromFunctionPointer.dataMatches(5));

    return 0;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/afYsTPoK4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial traits can be simplified using `std::conditional`:

```
template <typename T>
using GetDataType = std::conditional_t<std::is_invocable_v<T>,
                                       std::invoke_result<T>,
                                       std::type_identity<T>>::type;

template <typename T>
using GetSourceType = std::conditional_t<std::is_invocable_v<T>,
                                       std::type_identity_t<T>,
                                       std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<T>>>;
```

(From usage I would use `const T&` for non invokable for `GetDataType`)

Then

```
template <typename DataSource>
class DataGetter
{
public:
    using DataType = GetDataType<DataSource>;
    using DataSourceType = GetSourceType<DataSource>;

    DataGetter(const DataSource &f) : m_dataSource(f) {}

    [[nodiscard]] bool dataMatches(DataType refData) const
    {
        return refData == getData();
    }

private:
    DataSourceType m_dataSource;

    [[nodiscard]] DataType getData() const
    {
        if constexpr (std::invocable<DataSource>)
        {
            return std::invoke(m_dataSource);
        }
        else
        {
            return m_dataSource;
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y5bhWMeo7)

Comment: Thank you! I did initially try use `std::conditional`, but was getting errors. I see you used `std::conditional_t` and `::type` at the end for `GetDataType`, but `GetSourceType` does not have `::type` at the end. Could you help me understand how this works?

Comment: I think I got it, if I rewrite it as below, then it works too:
`template <typename T>
using GetSourceType = std::conditional_t<std::is_invocable_v<T>, std::type_identity<T>, std::add_lvalue_reference<std::add_const_t<T>>>::type;`

Comment: `std::invoke_result<T>` is valid for any `T`, **but** `std::invoke_result<T>::type` is only valid if `T` is invocable, so we have to delay its instantiation (so usage of `std::type_identity<T>` on the other side). and then the possibly strange `std::conditional<..>::type::type`.